# chrome extension disable notification sound on click of close notification button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have created reminder app which allows user to create , edit and delete reminder , i also created sound notification but i am facing one problem here when i click on close button of notification popup html it should make sound off insted of that it goes on. how do i resolve this?

following is my code of background.js

```
  function audioNotification(){
   var yourSound = new Audio('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg');
    yourSound.play();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a variable outside of the function so you can still have reference to that variable.

Try this

```
var yourSound; // <- moved outside of function

function audioNotification(){
  // ...
  yourSound = new Audio('http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/test.ogg');
  yourSound.play();
```

}

then to stop it call on your onclick() part

```
yourSound.pause()
```

btw, there is no .stop() function there
[image]

Comment: You're welcome Sona. Looks like you are doing a fun chrome extension too :)